# K&R C book, Exercise 1-21: Replace tabs with spaces

Tags: beginner, c, formatting, io

I'm new to C, just started reading K&R C book, and am working through exercises. This is my solution to 1-21, and as far as I tested it works.
Anything that I'm doing wrong, or that it's not idiomatic C? What can be improved ?

> Exercise 1-21. Write a program entab that replaces strings of blanks
>   by the minimum number of tabs and blanks to achieve the same spacing.
>   Use the same tab stops as for detab. When either a tab or a single
>   blank would suffice to reach a tab stop, which should be given
>   preference?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAB_SIZE 4

int main_entab() {
    int c;
    int character_count = 0;
    int whitespace_count = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {

        if (c == ' ') {

            // A _ B _ | _ C _ _ | 
            int numberOfCharsToReachTabStop = (TAB_SIZE - ((character_count + whitespace_count) % TAB_SIZE));

            whitespace_count++;

            if (numberOfCharsToReachTabStop == 1 && whitespace_count > 0) {
                putchar('\t');
                //advance count by how many whitespaces we are replacing, so next tab stop calculation is correct
                character_count = character_count + whitespace_count;
                whitespace_count = 0;
            }


        } else {
            //we encountered a non-whitespace char. Print all 'saved' whitespaces.
            while (whitespace_count > 0) {
                putchar(' ');
                whitespace_count--;
                character_count++;
            }

            //print the non-whitespace char
            character_count++;
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the tab size on a printer or terminal will be 8 characters, not 4 characters, so the posted code will fail to perform as desired

Comment: the `main()` function name is not optional.  It must be 'main' not 'main_entab'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Constants

> ```
> #define TAB_SIZE 4
> ```

This is the old way of doing things.  Modernly C uses the same syntax as C++:

```
const int TAB_SIZE = 4;
```

While both will still function, this has the added benefit of offering type safety.  The `#define` is just a search and replace used by the preprocessor.  I.e. it replaces `TAB_SIZE` with the character 4 in an intermediate copy of the file.  The `const` variable will be managed by the compiler.

#### Update assignments

> ```
>                 character_count = character_count + whitespace_count;
> ```

This is more idiomatically written

```
                character_count += whitespace_count;
```

That form is exactly the same as the longer form.  It evaluates the left-hand side of the assignment, adds it to the right-hand side, and stores the result in the left-hand side.  But it is shorter and more easily recognizable.

#### Simplifying logic

However, I wouldn't do either of these.  Instead, on each iteration of the loop, just increment `character_count`.  Then you never have to add `character_count` and `whitespace_count`.  This will work in your program because you never use `character_count` separately from `whitespace_count`.  So make this change and replace `character_count + whitespace_count` with just `character_count`.

#### Yoda conditions

> ```
>         if (c == ' ') {
> ```

This is often written as

```
        if (' ' == c) {
```

The reason is that if you accidentally leave off an equals sign `' ' = c` will generate a compiler error.  Meanwhile, `c = ' '` will silently do the wrong thing.  It wouldn't be so bad here, as it will be immediately obvious in the display.  But in a different kind of program, assigning to `c` might make a much more subtle bug.

#### Correct naming

> ```
>             //we encountered a non-whitespace char. Print all 'saved' whitespaces.
> ```

This is incorrect.  A whitespace is any character that can produce indent.  It specifically includes tabs (and new lines).  But what you check is non-space characters.  This is easy enough to fix, just remove "white" both times here and rename `whitespace_count` to `space_count`.

#### Consistent naming style

You have the camelCased `numberOfCharsToReachTabStop` and snake_cased `character_count` and `whitespace_count`.  Please pick one kind of casing per identifier type and stick to it.  If local variables are snake_cased, then `number_of_chars_to_reach_tab_stop`.  Or change them all to camelCase.  I personally prefer snake_case, which is easier for non-native English speakers, as it doesn't rely on an ability to differentiate between capital and lowercase letters.  But the most important thing is to be consistent so that people can see snake_case and realize that it is a local variable or one of the other things that use snake_case.

`TAB_SIZE` is a constant, so it is appropriate to use a different casing style (e.g. ALL_CAPS) for it.

#### Bugs

As already noted, you don't print spaces at the end of a line.  But there is a more serious bug.  You treat tabs as single characters in the character count.  You should not.  Instead, tabs are `TAB_SIZE` characters.  Don't forget to adjust for the tab stop.  I.e. if you are currently one character past the tab stop, you'd only add three characters for the tab.  So if you adopt my previous suggestion of incrementing `character_count` on every iteration, you need something like

```
if ('\t' == c) {
    /* update character_count appropriately */
} else {
    character_count++;
}
```

I'll leave the actual update to you, as that's the exercise that you're exploring.

Answer (score 3):

After `whitespace_count++`, the condition `&& whitespace_count > 0` will always be `true`, so can be removed.

Bug: if the file ends in space characters, these can be lost.

Comment: Unless `INT32_MAX == whitespace_count`. I would NOT advice to remove the condition.

Comment: @Nicolas `whitespace_count` is always non-negative.  It could only overflow if `TABSIZE == INT_MAX+1` which is already an overflow.

Answer (score 1):

the tab size on a printer or terminal will be 8 characters, not 4 characters, so the posted code will fail to perform as desired

the main() function name is not optional. It must be 'main' not 'main_entab'

Comment: Tab size I think is configurable. It's 4 on my machine. My guess is there should be a way to get the current size.

Yes, I know about the main, I was calling the main_entab() from another file that has the main function.